# Maximum size of unzipped package zip and lambda layers in AWS Lambda when ephemeral storage is increased

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

If we increase the ephemeral storage of a Lambda function up to 10GB (using the new configuration option which was just added by AWS) does this mean the maximum unzipped size of the package and the lambda layers is now larger, or is it unchanged?

The challenge we face is that our package and lambda layers files is quite small but when they are unzipped they hit the limits and I am wondering if increasing ephemeral storage will relieve this constraint.

[image]

Comment: Why not set it to 10GB and try it?

Comment: As the description says, it only impacts the size of the `/tmp` mount point.

Comment: Use lambda images and you will also have 10gb for your package

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt, since we are trying to deploy heavy python packages to our lambda, so I did set ephemeral storage at maximum, and tried to deploy tensorflow==2.10.0 as a requirement package (700 Mb unzipped).

Aaaan while trying to deploy it gave me the error "Unzipped size must be smaller than 211542732 bytes ..." So i guess ephemeral storage does not count for package requirements, but to process files when the lambda is already up with all of its packages.